# Using iOS 9 content blocker to block ads by presentation style

Tags: html, ios, safari, mobile-safari

Would it be possible to use Safari Content Blockers to block only certain types of ads, such as layer or video ads? I am a Cocoa/Touch dev and although I know some HTML/CSS/JS, what I don't know is what rules I could use to achieve this, as I lack a level of proficiency in web development that would allow me to intuit what elements I need to block. So my question is thus:
1. Is there a way to do this that would work across most sites?
2. If not, can I block it in a site-specific way by observing how a site serves its ads in the source code, and if so how likely are such rules to break often?
3. If the answer to any of the above is yes, could you provide an example?